# Intel compiler doesn't like auto end() const ->decltype(map.cend())

Tags: c++, c++11, intel

I have written some wrapped-code around an `std::unordered_map` just so I can temporarily use it for multi-threaded access (I know there are better ways of doing this).

As part of the class I have the following code allowing for-each iteration through the `std::unordered_map`:

```
auto begin() const ->decltype(map.cbegin()) { 
    return map.begin(); 
}

auto end()   const ->decltype(map.cend())   {
    return map.end(); 
}
```

but the Intel Compiler (**v14**) doesn't like this:

```
error #288: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
1>      auto begin() const ->decltype(map.cbegin()) { 

error #288: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
1>      auto end()   const ->decltype(map.cend())   {
```

Any suggestions how I could fix this? The above works on MSVC 12. I would prefer a solution which works on most compilers?

```
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <boost\shared_ptr>

class my_map {
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<int> > map;
    std::mutex mtx;

public:

    boost::shared_ptr<int>& operator[](std::string key)
    {
        return map[key];
    }

    auto begin() const ->decltype(map.cbegin()) { 
        return map.begin(); 
    }

    auto end()   const ->decltype(map.cend())   {
        return map.end(); 
    }
};
```

I have omitted the constructors and `insert()`.

**UPDATE**: Have found the problem, its when I change the type the `std::unordered_map` stores from `int` to `MyClass`.

Does `MyClass` need anything explicitly declared within it to get the above to work?

Comment: Can you show the full class definition?

Comment: I have posted most of it.

Comment: Which version of Intel's compiler are you using? I've tested on http://gcc.godbolt.org/, which shows 13.0.1 accepts your usage just fine. (I've added a `X` template parameter to `my_map`, and forced an instantiation of `my_map<int>`, to test.)

Comment: So you tried other compilers ? (the title suggests it)

Comment: Also what is X ? Is your class a template ?
Note: in operator[], key should be passed as a const to reference.

Comment: It works on MSVC 12, Doesn't work on ICC 13.

Comment: @user997112 [Here's the link to the *exact* code that I tested, which you can see does work on ICC 13.](http://goo.gl/1MFxsp) If you try *only* that with your local copy of ICC, does it work, or do you get the same error for that? If *that* does work, it's possible that some other part of your code (that isn't part of your question) is triggering an unexpected error in unrelated code for some reason. Or, it could show that my testcase is incorrect, in which case I welcome an improvement. :)

Comment: @hvd I have changed my code above to show what I have, X was representing a shared_ptr class. I am also actually using ICC 14! Apologies, I did a software update and this changes the compiler version.

Comment: I tried gcc 4.7 and 4.8, ICC 13 and ICC 14, all work (Linux/Ubuntu 14).

Comment: Ok I have found the problem- its because of the underlying object type I am storing in the unordered_map. If I replace "int" with MyClass I get the error. What properties does MyClass need to fulfill in order to allow the decltype feature?